# Change name in axis x label plot_model

Tags: r

How can I change the name in the x label? for=cicatriz to= Cicatríz umbilical

```
set_theme(base = theme_classic(), #To remove the background color and the grids
          theme.font = 'serif',   #To change the font type
          axis.title.size = 1.5,  #To change axis title size
          axis.textsize.x = 1.2,  #To change x axis text size
          axis.textsize.y = 1.2)  #To change y axis text size

plot_model(mod_plasmacic, type="pred", show.p = TRUE, axis.title = (expression(paste(delta^{13}, "C(‰)"))), title = "")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBEw1.jpg)

Comment: You should change it to "Cicatriz umbilical" *not* "Cicatríz umbilical" as cicatriz has no tilde (*palabra aguda terminada en consonante distinta de n o s*, e.g. like "feliz", "perdiz", "calor", "ciudad", "pincel", ... The confusion comes more likely because "z" sounds like "s" and words like "anís", "arnés", "Tomás" do carry a tilde. (And of course you can check this on any spanish dictionary :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
set_theme(base = theme_classic(), #To remove the background color and the grids
          theme.font = 'serif',   #To change the font type
          axis.title.size = 1.5,  #To change axis title size
          axis.textsize.x = 1.2,  #To change x axis text size
          axis.textsize.y = 1.2)  #To change y axis text size

plot_model(mod, type="pred", show.p = TRUE, axis.title = c("Cicatríz umbilical",expression(paste(delta^{13}, "C(‰)"))), title = "")
```

[image]